# BigQuery SQL, CASE WHEN/ IF question about code editing. Easy level

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Does anyone know how to edit this code to make it work? It's my first CASE WHEN. I'm trying to do it same way like another language but maybe I'm wrong. I want to do this "if" 3 times but now I will be happy if know how to do 1st. Ty for help!

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IXhL.png),

[table column name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw9C2.png)

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with the case itself.

Your group by might need work though.

Try changing your group by to this:

```
group by email, priority
```

Comment: perfect it works! ty ^.^